RaspPi5 + ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to load my camera 0v5647 via csi connection. I can see video0 under dev but can't load it with anything (camera_ros package, image_view, sourced manually rpicam). I have made all the changes needed in the config.txt. I am wondering if anyone managed to solve this.

What is a csi connection?
